# Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types

Tags: rust

There are several wrapper types in the Rust standard library:

- The cells in the [`std::cell` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html#structs): [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) and [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html)
- The reference-counted wrappers, like [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html).
- The types in the [`std::sync` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/index.html): [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html) for example

As I understand it, these are wrappers which provide further possibilities than a simple reference. While I understand some basics, I cannot  see the whole picture.

What do they do exactly? Do cells and reference-counted families provide orthogonal or similar features?

Comment: Please describe *what* you don't understand. The documentation you've linked to has had hundreds (or thousands) of people read it, and likely tens to hundreds of people contribute to it. What can we possibly say that would be any different from what is already said, especially if you don't tell us what you don't understand?

Comment: @Shepmaster The explanations in the documentation speak about *interior mutability*. This concept is unclear for me. Maybe my question has been unclear too.

Comment: A quick internet search found [a chapter in the book about interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html), a [blog post](https://ricardomartins.cc/2016/06/08/interior-mutability), and [a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32062285/155423). Perhaps now that you know what you are unclear about, you can perform some research and update your question.

Comment: Updated link to the latest version of the book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html

Answer (score 182, accepted):

There are two essential concepts in Rust:

- Ownership,
- Mutability.

The various pointer types (`Box`, `Rc`, `Arc`) are concerned with *Ownership*: they allow controlling whether there is a single or multiple owners for a single object.

On the other hand, the various cells (`Cell`, `RefCell`, `Mutex`, `RwLock`, `AtomicXXX`) are concerned with *Mutability*.

---

The founding rule of Rust's safety is **Aliasing NAND Mutability**. That is, an object can only be safely mutated if there is no outstanding reference to its interior.

This rule is generally enforced at compile time by the *borrow checker*:

- if you have a `&T`, you cannot also have a `&mut T` to the same object in scope,
- if you have a `&mut T`, you cannot also have any reference to the same object in scope.

However, sometimes, this is not flexible enough. Sometimes you DO need (or want) the ability to have multiple references to the same object and yet mutate it. Enter the **cells**.

The idea of `Cell` and `RefCell` is to permit mutability in the presence of aliasing *in a controlled manner*:

- `Cell` prevents the formation of reference to its interior, avoiding dangling references,
- `RefCell` shifts the enforcement of **Aliasing XOR Mutability** from compile time to runtime.

This functionality is sometimes described as providing **interior mutability**, that is where an object which otherwise looks immutable from the outside (`&T`) can actually be mutated.

When this mutability extends across multiple threads, you will instead use `Mutex`, `RwLock` or `AtomicXXX`; they provide the same functionality:

- `AtomicXXX` are just `Cell`: no reference to the interior, just moving in/out,
- `RwLock` is just `RefCell`: can obtain references to the interior through *guards*,
- `Mutex` is a simplified version of `RwLock` which does not distinguish between a read-only guard and write guard; so conceptually similar to a `RefCell` with only a `borrow_mut` method.

---

If you come from a C++ background:

- `Box` is `unique_ptr`,
- `Arc` is `shared_ptr`,
- `Rc` is a non thread-safe version of `shared_ptr`.

And the cells provide a similar functionality as `mutable`, except with additional guarantees to avoid aliasing issues; think of `Cell` as `std::atomic` and `RefCell` as a non thread-safe version of `std::shared_mutex` (which throws instead of blocking if the lock is taken).

Comment: Thank you *so* much, you answer exactly to all my perplexity about "complicated" types in Rust. The comparison with C++ is perfect, also.

Comment: The term **aliasing**, though, beats me. I understand it as "multiple reference on a data", is it that?

Comment: @Boiethios: Yes, that's exactly that. Each reference/pointer is "an alias" to the real data (a different name for the same "person" is what an alias is, after all), and by extension in software we talk about aliasing when there are multiple aliases at a given time.

Comment: The first edition of the book had [a chapter on this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/choosing-your-guarantees.html). It's one of the ones that was lost in the rewrite, which I think is unfortunate -- maybe it should be made into an appendix or something

Comment: If **Aliasing XOR Mutability** is the rule for safety, that implies that **(not Aliasing) AND (not Mutability)** is unsafe? But surely, if there is no aliasing AND no mutability then that is totally safe? I think you want something else than XOR there.

Comment: @Lii: *Coward's way out* => just citing core developers' slide, I'll keep with their slogan ;)

Comment: Maybe the slogan should use NAND instead of XOR :P

Comment: What does "prevents the formation of reference to its interior" even mean? This is what I hate about the documentation that's there. I actually already know what `Cell` does, but this kind of explanation is unnecessary. It doesn't need to be explained like an academic proof.

Comment: @sep What's your alternative to explain the concept? I found that to be pretty much on spot. In case that was a genuine question: It means that you gain interior mutability by giving up the ability to hold references to said interiors. Is that less academic enough?

Answer (score 49):

Thanks to [Matthieu's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674912/4498831), here is a diagram to help people to find the wrapper they need:

```
+-----------+
| Ownership |
+--+--------+                              +================+
   |                         +-Static----->| T              |(1)
   |                         |             +================+
   |                         |
   |                         |             +================+
   |          +-----------+  | Local    Val| Cell<T>        |(1)
   +-Unique-->| Borrowing +--+-Dynamic---->|----------------|
   |          +-----------+  |          Ref| RefCell<T>     |(1)
   |                         |             +================+
   |                         |
   |                         |             +================+
   |                         | Threaded    | AtomicT        |(2)
   |                         +-Dynamic---->|----------------|
   |                                       | Mutex<T>       |(1)
   |                                       | RwLock<T>      |(1)
   |                                       +================+
   |
   |
   |                                       +================+
   |                         +-No--------->| Rc<T>          |
   |                         |             +================+
   | Locally  +-----------+  |
   +-Shared-->| Mutable?  +--+             +================+
   |          +-----------+  |          Val| Rc<Cell<T>>    |
   |                         +-Yes-------->|----------------|
   |                                    Ref| Rc<RefCell<T>> |
   |                                       +================+
   |
   |
   |                                       +================+
   |                         +-No--------->| Arc<T>         |
   |                         |             +================+
   | Shared   +-----------+  |
   +-Between->| Mutable?  +--+             +================+
     Threads  +-----------+  |             | Arc<AtomicT>   |(2)
                             +-Yes-------->|----------------|
                                           | Arc<Mutex<T>>  |
                                           | Arc<RwLock<T>> |
                                           +================+
```

1. In those cases, `T` can be replaced with `Box<T>`
2. Use [`AtomicT`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html#structs) when `T` is a `bool` or a number

---

To know if you should use `Mutex` or `RwLock`, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704279/when-or-why-should-i-use-a-mutex-over-an-rwlock/50704283).