# How to keep state within a custom global allocator?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write my own custom global allocator that will need to keep some state. Consider the following non-compiling code:

```
#![feature(rustc_private)]

use std::alloc::{GlobalAlloc, Layout};

extern crate libc;

struct MyAllocator {
    offset: usize,
}

unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for MyAllocator {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, _layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        let ret = libc::malloc(_layout.size() as libc::size_t) as *mut u8;
        self.offset += _layout.size() as usize;
        ret
    }
    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, _ptr: *mut u8, _layout: Layout) {}
}

#[global_allocator]
static A: MyAllocator = MyAllocator { offset: 0 };

fn main() {
    println!("it runs!");
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `self.offset` which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
12 |     unsafe fn alloc(&self, _layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
   |                     ----- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut self`
13 |         let ret = libc::malloc(_layout.size() as libc::size_t) as *mut u8;
14 |         self.offset += _layout.size() as usize;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written
```

How to solve this one? I can see some example code in [this repository](https://github.com/phil-opp/linked-list-allocator/blob/master/src/lib.rs), but can't see what part specifically makes it possible to convert `&self` to `&mut self`.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45674479/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered. [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=18f9dad7b69ec53fa2f823dea58ece22)

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but if you aren't yet familiar with fundamental Rust concepts like interior mutability, writing a custom allocator in Rust may not be an appropriately-sized project.

Comment: Please do not use leading underscores for variables that are used. Leading underscores indicate that a variable is **deliberately left unused**.

Comment: *can't see what part specifically makes it possible* — the data is inside a mutex that is subsequently locked.