# Why does serde::json need to copy this ref?

Tags: rust, serde-json

Here's some simple code that seems like it should work:

```rust
use serde_json;
use std::io::Write;

fn test(writer: &mut dyn Write) {
    serde_json::to_writer(writer, "test1").unwrap();
    serde_json::to_writer(writer, "test2").unwrap();
}
```

But it produces the following error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `writer`
  --> src/main.rs:35:27
   |
33 | fn test(writer: &mut dyn Write) {
   |         ------ move occurs because `writer` has type `&mut dyn std::io::Write`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
34 |     serde_json::to_writer(writer, "test1").unwrap();
   |                           ------ value moved here
35 |     serde_json::to_writer(writer, "test2").unwrap();
   |                           ^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

To get it to work, I have to jump through this hoop:

```rust
fn test(writer: &mut dyn Write) {
    serde_json::to_writer(&mut *writer, "test1").unwrap();
    serde_json::to_writer(writer, "test2").unwrap();
}
```

What is going on here? Why can I "manually" copy the ref by deref/re-referencing it, but it doesn't implement Copy?

---

This is specifically something to do with the generic type signature of `serde_json::to_writer`, because it also works fine with a different function:

```rust
fn test(x: &mut dyn Write) {
    x.write_all(b"test1").unwrap();
    x.write_all(b"test2").unwrap(); 
}
```

Comment: TL/DR the duplicate: Rust reborrows implicitly when the compiler expects an explicit `&mut` reference (as in your second example), but `serde_json::to_writer` takes a generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust `&T` implements `Copy`. However, `&mut T` doesn't. It has to be moved (because of [Aliasing NAND Mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674912/8564999))

In your case `writer` being a `&mut T` is moved out into `serde_json::to_writer` and afterwards the reference is unusable for another call. However, for convenience Rust allows to borrow mutably from a mutable refenrence in simple cases - only if this borrow will die before the original mutable reference is used. This is what you did in your quesion, you may consider it as a "temporary reversable ownership transfer"

Trying to use it in other ways would fail. For example, this one uses the original mutable reference before the the secondary borrow is eliminated.

```
fn test(writer: &mut dyn Write) {
    let mut w = &mut *writer;
    serde_json::to_writer(writer, "test1").unwrap();
    serde_json::to_writer(w, "test1").unwrap();
}
```

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `writer` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:6:27
  |
5 |     let mut w = &mut *writer;
  |                 ------------ borrow of `*writer` occurs here
6 |     serde_json::to_writer(writer, "test1").unwrap();
  |                           ^^^^^^ move out of `writer` occurs here
7 |     serde_json::to_writer(w, "test1").unwrap();
  |                           - borrow later used here
```

And this one tries to create multiple temprorary mutable borrows at the same time

```
fn test(writer: &mut dyn Write) {
    let mut w = &mut *writer;
    let mut w1 = &mut *writer;
    serde_json::to_writer(w, "test1").unwrap();
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*writer` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:6:18
  |
5 |     let mut w = &mut *writer;
  |                 ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
6 |     let mut w1 = &mut *writer;
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
7 |     serde_json::to_writer(w, "test1").unwrap();
  |                           - first borrow later used here
```