# How do I realize double linked mutable references?

Tags: rust

I want to create a struct which referecnces to it self like following:

```
struct Item<'a> {
    id: String,
    children: Vec<&'a mut Item<'a>>,
    parents: Vec<&'a mut Item<'a>>
}
```

At the moment I use a hashmap for all Items and save the `id: String` in the children/parents vectors.
I am curious how I can improve the performance and usablility by avoiding the hashmap lookup for all my related ids with references. It is working with unmutable borrowed references, but then I loose the advantage to add or remove children/parents from related Items.
Because one Item can be linked to multiple other Items, I would need multiple mutable references which is prohibited. Is it possible with `Rc` and `RefCell`?

How do I design a datatype like this correctly or is it nonsense?

Comment: I don't think two structs can [hold direct mutable references to each other](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021)?

Comment: The link only shows a hello world program?

Comment: Aargh sorry everybody thought I had and of course when I clicked the link it showed my code because it saves it in localStorage. Here's the fixed link https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7cf2d56eab2f3d2ad1e44f8cbd5fd19a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use references because you would have 2 ways of obtaining the same mutable reference one is `&mut self` the other is along `self.children[x].parents[y]` where `parent[y]` of `child[x]` is `self` but mutable references have to be exclusive.
And yes you can use interior mutability using `Cell`, `RefCell`, `Mutex` or `RwLock` [depending on your usecase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674479/need-holistic-explanation-about-rusts-cell-and-reference-counted-types) instead.
Additionally add `Rc` or `Arc` (or the respective `Weak` for the `parents`) for the shared ownership.

If performance is critical you might have to go the way `std`s `LinkedList` went and use `unsafe` with raw pointers instead.